# CustomSD service not able to play tracks

Tags: sonos

I’m currently developing a music service and testing it via customsd. The integration in the controller app is working (iOS App & Windows Desktop App) - so I can browse - but I can’t get a Player to play any track. I keep receiving ‘unable to connect’ errors once I hit the ‘Play’ button in the controller. I can see on the service side that the Player sends a getMetadata and a getMediaURI request, and the SOAP responses delivered by the service are identical to working examples from another source; however, the Player seems unable to process them. I am kind of stuck, and I guess what would help me are the Player logs. Is there any way to get them?
Or, does anyone have any other idea about the root cause of the issue?

EDIT: More or less accidentally, I came across the reason of my problem. Whereas in general, Sonos can handle arbitrary IDs, getMediaURI only seems to work when it requests the URI for an ID of the form track:something. I don‘t remember seeing this as a requirement on the developer pages.

Anyway, got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a `getMediaURI` request and responding to it with a valid response, then most likely the player is failing to process the media file itself. Are you seeing the media file being downloaded? You could host the media file locally and include the URI to that in the `getMediaURI` response to check.

Note that the `<mimeType>` included in the metadata is used to inform the player of the type of media the URI in the `getMediaURL` response points to.

So if you were to return `<mimeType>audio/ogg</mimeType>` for track123, but `getMediaURI`'s response contained the URI `https://something.xyz/track123.mp3`, playback would likely fail due to the mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [bonob](https://github.com/simojenki/bonob)? Someone made a music service emulator for **navidrome** (self-hosted music library, a la spotify). It should be a great resource to get you started.

He wrote that your music service has to be available at https for it to even start functioning.

Note, I'm the developer of [sonos-ts](https://svrooij.io/node-sonos-ts/) a library to control sonos speakers from typescript and node. And the external music services are documented [here](https://svrooij.io/sonos-api-docs/music-services.html)